# Add pause after SpeakAsync string

Tags: c++-cli, text-to-speech

I need to pause a SpeakAsync call for a second (after the end of the reading).

Something like this:

```
String^ MyString = "AString";
SpeechSynthesizer^ synth = gcnew SpeechSynthesizer();
synth->SpeakAsync(MyString);
//pause here
```

How can I accomplish this task?
Thanks in advance,
Marco L.

Comment: Will the simple `Thread::Sleep(1000)` work for you?

Comment: I don't want the main thread to be paused; infact I'm using the Asyncronous version of the SpeechSynthesizer

Comment: What is your goal here? When the async sound is done, what is happening that you want to happen one second later?